# Best way to export a csv file in Excel Addin

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I'm a fairly new coder and trying to write a simple add-in to export an Excel table to csv format.  Whilst this is easily possible using VBA, I would like to be forward thinking and use the add-in model if I can. I've looked through the API docs, but can't find anything to do it (such as SaveAs)- could anyone please offer me some pointers?

Many thanks

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest [grabbing the table's range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt598663.aspx#getrange), loading its values and doing the conversion to CSV yourself.

Your code should look something like this :

```js
Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
    var table = ctx.workbook.tables.getItem(tableName);
    var tableRange = table.getRange();
    tableRange.load('values'); 
    return ctx.sync().then(function() {
        ConvertToCSV(tableRange.values);
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

Please let me know how this works out for you.

Gabriel Royer - Developer on the Office Extensibility Team, MSFT

Comment: Thanks Gab,  I'll give that a go and get back to you

Comment: This worked great - thanks Gab.

For converting to csv I used the the [html5csv](https://github.com/DrPaulBrewer/html5csv) library.